# Is the QGIS blog broken?

Tags: qgis, api

I would like to use the QGIS API in my own program to display maps ....

So I thought I would find some tutorial here :
http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Writing_custom_Applications_with_QGIS_API

But the links are directed towards the qgis blog (http://blog.qgis.org/?q=node/10), which seems to be "down" ....

Where can I find such tutorials ?

Best regards.

Comment: The Given link is working for me.

Answer (score 4):

This resource is outdated. Please refer to the new [Python Cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/index.html) which covers many more topics and is up to date.

For further reference: I'll edit the Wiki to remove those dead links.